# CodeIgniter library dompdf: How to download Pdf file directly, without asking for saving pdf in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

CodeIgniter library dompdf: How to download Pdf file directly, without asking for saving pdf in codeIgniter?

vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

```
  class Pdfgenerator {
  public function generate($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE, $paper = 'A4', $orientation = "portrait")
  {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: this question is a little bit unclear, what do you mean by download, you do not download anything in this function, you only return pdf, is that what you mean? if so you probably just want to omit if/else and simply return I guess.

Comment: thanks for reply, i just updated to latest version of dompdf, using composer, in codeIgniter. can u suggest steps,

Comment: this issuevendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory